# How to launch a process for reading and writing in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process

Background: I have to revive my old program, which unfortunately fails when it comes to communication with subprocess. The program is written in C++ and creates subprocess for writing with opened pipe for reading. Nothing crashes, but there is no data to read.

My idea is to recreate entire scenario in bash, so I could interactively check what is going on.

Things I used in C++:

- `mkfifo` for creating pipe, there is a bash equivalent
- `popen` for creating subprocess (in my case for writing)

  ```
  espeak -x -q -z 1> /dev/null 2> /tmp/my-pipe
  ```
- `open` and `read` -- for opening the pipe and then reading, I hope simple `cat` will suffice
- `fwrite` -- for writing to subprocess, will just redirection work?

So I hope `open`, `read` and `fwrite` will be straightforward, but how do I launch a program as a process (what is `popen` in bash)?

Comment: Why recreate it in bash when you can just debug it in gdb?

Comment: @JimGarrison, and what I would do in gdb? It does not crash, or anything like this, for every command I have assert that ensures execution didn't fail. There is no data in pipe.

Comment: You would set a breakpoint where you believe the program writes to the pipe.  If the breakpoint is not hit then back up to an earlier point, repeating until you find where the program behavior deviates from what you expect it to be doing.  This is fundamental debugging and will get you an answer a lot faster than simulating it with something that won't behave the same way.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I still don't get it. What do you mean by "break"? The data are written correctly, the data are read correctly. There is no error in sense that some command failed. So I don't have to run gdb, I know which command is unable to read, it is `select` which reports there is nothing to read. The problem is I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply run the process in the background.

```
espeak -x -q -z >/dev/null 2>/tmp/mypipe &
```

Comment: Wait. How do you specify the process is for writing or for reading?

Comment: I assumed you would read from the pipe to which the process writes (its standard error). If the process is meant to read from data you provide, you would redirect its input from a pipe which you write to (`espeak < /tmp/otherpipe`).

Comment: @chepner Last time I checked, `espeak` doesn't do anything until `EOF` is reached. And I think I tried `-z` as well to fix it. Is it working now as expected?

Comment: @konsolebox, how do you send EOF (I use `fflush` to mark that I am done with sending data). I could use `fclose`, but I have more data to send after some time, so I wrote my program to send and read data in chunks (it worked before).

Answer (score 1):

bash naturally makes piping between processes very easy, so commands to create and open pipes are not normally needed

```
program1 | program2
```

This is the equivalent of program1 running `popen("program2","w");`
It could also be achieved by program2 running `popen("program1","r");`

If you explicitly want to use a named pipe:

```
 mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
 program1 >/tmp/mypipe  &
 program2 </tmp/mypipe  
 rm /tmp/mypipe
```

Comment: But in my case it is long-lasting process, so simply piping it as you shown in first piece won't suffice. How do you send data to program1 in your second example after launching it?

Comment: In the example, program1 is the writer.  presumably you mean "how do I send data to program2?"

Comment: assuming you have a process that is reading from the pipe and in the background `myprogram </tmp/mypipe &`  you can send data to it any time such as  `echo stuff >/tmp/mypipe`

Comment: the subprocess should be able to read and write. So my question was OK (I could ask how to read from program2 as well).

Answer (score 1):

A thought that might solve your original problem (and is a consideration for using pipes in shell):

Using stdio commands such as popen, fwrite, etc involve buffering.   If a program on the write end of the pipe only writes a small amount of data to the pipe, the program on the reading end won't see any of it until a full block of data has been written to the pipe, after which, the block of data will be pushed along the pipe.   If you wish to have the data get there sooner, you need either call fflush() on the writing end, or fclose() if you are not planning on sending any more data.   Note that with bash, I don't believe there is any equivalent of fflush.

Comment: Thank you, I already use `fflush`. It is peculariar, 5 years ago it worked, I just recompiled it, no problem here, but it does not communicate to other processes any longer.